# Vue 2.7 With Composition API + Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

We're trying to migrate our Vue 2 application to Vue 2.7 and having some issues with the composition API and Vuex.

In our current application, we're using the `@vue/composition-api` package to let us use composables. Within those composables we need access to the store, and get it like this:

```
...rest of the component
setup(props, { parent }) {
  const store = parent.$store
  someComposable({ store })
}
```

However, when we upgrade our version of Vue to 2.7 this syntax is no longer supported. We need to use the `useStore` composable from Vuex to get access to the store. This is only available on Vuex version 4.

When upgrading Vuex version 4 on our current version of Vue, we see the following errors:

```
 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 14:9-15
 export 'inject' (imported as 'inject') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24

 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 132:14-25
 export 'effectScope' (imported as 'effectScope') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24

 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 140:27-35
 export 'computed' (imported as 'computed') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24

 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 148:17-25
 export 'reactive' (imported as 'reactive') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24

 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 362:2-7
 export 'watch' (imported as 'watch') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24

 WARNING in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js 1101:9-14
 export 'watch' (imported as 'watch') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)
  @ ./src/plugins/vuex.js 4:0-24 5:8-12
  @ ./src/app.js 11:0-24
```

This makes sense because these are part of the composition API, and aren't available on the version of Vue that we're on (2.6.14). But it doesn't seem like Vuex version 4 and Vue version 2.7 work together either.

When we run our application with Vuex `^4.1.0` and Vue `2.7.13` we see the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store is undefined"
```

**How can we get Vue 2.7 working with Vuex and the composition API? Specifically, how can we get access to the Vuex store in our composables on Vue 2.7?**

Comment: Vuex 4 is for Vue 3.

Comment: Okay. Is it not possible to use composables, Vuex, and Vue 2.7 at the same time?

Comment: You can use composables in 2.7, not for Vuex 3 because it doesn't support composition specifically. You can still access it from `ctx.root.$store` or `getCurrentInstance()` in setup

Comment: getCurrentInstance is already deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209080/vue-3-is-getcurrentinstance-deprecated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your store:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({ ...options })
export default store;
export const useStore = () => store
```

In any component, including the child:

```js
setup() {
  const store = useStore();
  // ...
}
```

If you have more than one store, name the stores and their `use` functions accordingly.

Comment: In this case useStore is not really needed, can be kept for compatibility with V3. It isn't different than importing `store` directly.

Comment: The difference is it's imported when the component using it is created, not when the  store is created. I've had trouble in the past importing the store directly, especially in non-component files (e.g: axios config, etc...). In principle it should be the same thing, yes. Another (rather hackish) approach, which always works, is to `export const { $store } = app` from `main`, after mounting the app instance. When nothing else works, this does.

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, useStore won't help against circular deps here because `store` is created on the first import any way, it's handled with ESM circular dep resolution. It's rarely the case for a store in my experience because it's used inside other functions that aren't evaluated immediately, like axios interceptors. The thing that would work is to lazily create it, `let store; export let useStore = () => store || (store = new Store(...)`, this is why Pinia enforces the use of useStore

Comment: Any idea how to do this in nuxt?

Comment: @Cesar, no, I don't use nuxt. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507274/1891677) help?

Comment: I have a bigger problem, here's the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888285/how-to-export-reactive-vuex-state-from-setup-in-vue2-7

Comment: this can cause a dependency cycle error when you are using namespaced stores and try to import any composable in any of your namespaced stores