# How to export reactive Vuex state from setup in Vue2.7

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Here's a reproduction link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-c6mn17?file=src/components/Test.vue

I want to be able to use reactive state from that store using setup in Vue 2.7.

I export a Vuex store using `export const store = new Vuex.Store({ ... })`

Both of these fail:

```
const count1 = store.state.count;
const count2 = ref(store.state.count);
```

Doesn't work when exporting the store as a function either: `export const useStore = () => store` and doing `useStore().state ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or `toRef`/`toRefs`

```
const { count } = toRefs(store.state);
const count1 = toRef(store.state, "count");
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dygfna?file=src/components/Test.vue)

Answer (score 1):

use computed:

```
import { computed } from "vue"

const count2 = computed(() => store.state.count);
```