# How to make visible the "nuxtServerInit" action for Nuxt.js action in the case with dynamic modules only?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-module-decorators

According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60886837/4818123), below listing from the [vuex-module-decorators official documentation](https://championswimmer.in/vuex-module-decorators/)

```js
// @/store/index.ts
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  /*
  Ideally if all your modules are dynamic
  then your store is registered initially
  as a completely empty object
  */
})
```

in the Nuxt case must be:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex, { Store } from "vuex";


Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store: Store<unknown> = new Vuex.Store<unknown>({});
```

But how to integrate the [`nuxtServerInit`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) action is above methodology?
In below listing of `store/index.ts`, the `nuxtServerInit` will not be called.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex, { Store } from "vuex";


Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store: Store<unknown> = new Vuex.Store<unknown>({
  actions: {
    nuxtServerInit(context: unknown): void {
      console.log("Called !");
      console.log(context);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

`nuxtServerInit` can be used only in `store/index.js` file, this is server side action and can not be used from the client side.

> Only the primary module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to chain your module actions from there.

> The nuxtServerInit Action
> If the action nuxtServerInit is defined in the store and the mode is universal, Nuxt will call it with the context (**only from the server-side**). It's useful when we have some data on the server we want to give directly to the client-side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but I did not understand how I should to solve the problem. ""nuxtServerInit can be used only in store/index.js"" - Is `store/index.ts` O'K? If so, it does not work because code listing in the question is `store/index.ts`.

Comment: I am sorry to say it, but your answer is not including the working solution. Please answer me how I must to edit my `store/index.ts`  which listing I added to question field.